# Can we set the Convertible attribute using Castle Windsors Fluent API

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, web-config, castle-windsor, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to populate a collection of objects from the web.config of my api. I have all of the properties of these objects being pulled out correctly apart from one, which is another custom object within our object.

Now, if I add the convertible attribute to the class, it all works fine, but that breaks our Onion Architecture by adding an outward reference to castle.windsor in our Domain. The complex parameters with teh convertible attribute is detailed [here](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.XML-Inline-Parameters.ashx)

The Xml in the castle section of the web.config (with fluff removed) looks like this:

```
<component id="uniqueId" type="Project.Domain.Objects.Object, Project.Domain">
    <parameters>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Name>name1</Name>
    <geofenceLocation>
      <parameters>
      <latitude>12</latitude>
      <longitude>44</longitude>
      <radius>100</radius>
      </parameters>
    </geofenceLocation>
    </parameters>
  </component>
```

The object that I am trying to get to serialize without adding the convertible attribute is the geofenceLocation object. Is there a way to inject Attributes to the object so we can inject the Convertible attribute in the Api, or is there some other way to resolve this?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle geofencelocation as a new component like this:

```
<component id="geofenceLocation" type="your.type.here, your.assembly">
    <parameters>
      <latitude>12</latitude>
      <longitude>44</longitude>
      <radius>100</radius>
    </parameters>
</component>
```

and the reference to it from your other component like this:

```
<component id="uniqueId" type="Project.Domain.Objects.Object, Project.Domain">
    <parameters>
      <Id>1</Id>
      <Name>name1</Name>
      <geofenceLocation>${geofenceLocation}</geofenceLocation>
    </parameters>
</component>
```

Hope it helps. Bye

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We have decided to store these in a Data table for now. I've seen this solution about before, but I thought it would lead to a really cluttered config file, so I wanted to avoid it.

Comment: You are welcome. If you think my answer is the general solution for most cases please mark it as the correct answer so it can help other people. Thank you

Comment: I will accept it, as it does solve the problem I was looking at. If anyone else comes with a cleaner solution that fits the above issue better, feel free to add it somewhere and let me know :)